# Why aren't instance variables listed in inspect for the subclasses of built-in classes?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass

Why is there a change in behaviour in inspect when I subclass the built in class. But not seen when I am subclassing a custom one.

```
class MainError
end

class AnotherTestError < StandardError
  def initialize
    @label_test = "hey!"
  end
end

class TestError < MainError
  def initialize
    @label_test = "hey!"
  end
end

a = AnotherTestError.new
puts a.inspect # output: #<AnotherTestError: AnotherTestError>

t = TestError.new
puts t.inspect # output: #<TestError:0x007f99e12409f0 @label_test="hey!">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because many (most? all?) built-in classes

- are written in C, and
- have `#inspect` overriden.

For example, [`Exception`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Exception.html#method-i-inspect) (super class of `StandardError`) defines `#inspect` as follows:

```c
exc_inspect(VALUE exc)
{
    VALUE str, klass;

    klass = CLASS_OF(exc);
    exc = rb_obj_as_string(exc);
    if (RSTRING_LEN(exc) == 0) {
        return rb_str_dup(rb_class_name(klass));
    }

    str = rb_str_buf_new2("#<");
    klass = rb_class_name(klass);
    rb_str_buf_append(str, klass);
    rb_str_buf_cat(str, ": ", 2);
    rb_str_buf_append(str, exc);
    rb_str_buf_cat(str, ">", 1);

    return str;
}
```

The interesting part is building the return string.

---

[`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect), on the other hand defines:

```c
static VALUE
rb_obj_inspect(VALUE obj)
{
    if (rb_ivar_count(obj) > 0) {
        VALUE str;
        VALUE c = rb_class_name(CLASS_OF(obj));

        str = rb_sprintf("-<%"PRIsVALUE":%p", c, (void*)obj);
        return rb_exec_recursive(inspect_obj, obj, str);
    }
    else {
        return rb_any_to_s(obj);
    }
}
```

which recursively includes the instance variables with name and value.

Comment: Yes..It has been overridden.

Comment: Indeed, "overridden" is the word I was missing. Thanks :-)

Comment: To check where it is defined: `StandardError.instance_method(:inspect).owner
# => Exception`

Comment: But I didn't get why it was overridden?

Comment: I guess the stacktrace is kind of a beast to display in this form. Also, if you are ever in the need of handling an Exception (sub-) class, your code already is in a `rescue` block and should handle the exception properly (i.e. logging `e.message` and `e.backtrace` to a log file/`$stderr` and not just printing `e.inspect` to `$stdout`)...